# need help...contact matching for SMS

Tags: android

Checkout my code I have been doing some work on an sms application and I am trying now to match the address that has came with the sms with the number that has been stored in the contacts...

So far I was unable to match the contact and display the name of the sender because on emulator contains only two contacts... It matches the first one and displays its name while on phone it doesnot finds a single contact...

```
public List<String> getSMS() {

        List<String> sms = new ArrayList<String>();
        Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
        Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null,
                null);

        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor contactsCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                null, null, null, null);
        Cursor phoneCur = cr.query(
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                "DISPLAY_NAME = '" + name + "'", null, null);

        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "going in loop");
        if (contactsCur.getCount() > 0) {
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "inside loop");
            while (contactsCur.moveToNext()) {
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "cursor moving to next");
                id = contactsCur.getString(contactsCur
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                Log.i(LOG_TAG,"this is id: " + id);

                name = contactsCur
                        .getString(contactsCur
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                Cursor phones = cr.query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                        Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = " + id, null, null);
                Log.i(LOG_TAG, "This is name "+name);
                while (phones.moveToNext()) 
                {
                     number = phones.getString(phones
                            .getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
                     String aNumber=number.replaceAll("-", "");
                     Log.i(LOG_TAG,"this is number :"+aNumber);

                    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "getting address and message");

                    while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                        String address = cur.getString(cur
                                .getColumnIndex("address"));
                        if(address.equals(aNumber))
                            address=name;
                        String body = cur.getString(cur
                                .getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));

                        sms.add("Number: " + address+ " .Message: " + body);
                    }
                    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "closing phone cursor");
                    phoneCur.close();
                }

            }
        }

        return sms;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't completely understood what you coded here.But I got your requirement.So my suggestion is-try this way(I haven't tried it because of the lack of time for now,but logically it should work):

```
public List<String> getSMS() {

        List<String> sms = new ArrayList<String>();
        //fetch all inbox sms
        Cursor inboxCursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null,null);

        if(inboxCursor.getCount()>0)
        {
            inboxCursor.moveToFirst();
            for(int i=0;i<inboxCursor.getCount();i++)
            {
                //get phone-number of sms
                String address=inboxCursor.getString(inboxCursor.getColumnIndex("address"));

                //fetch contacts with same phone-number
                Cursor contactCursor=getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER+"='"+address+"'",null,null);

                if(contactCursor.getCount()>0)
                {
                    contactCursor.moveToFirst();

                    // fetch the name associated with that number in contacts saved
                    String name=contactCursor.getString(contactCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    //add number,name,message to list   
                    sms.add("Number: " + address+ " .Name: "+ name +".Message: " + body);
                }
                else 
                {  
                    // for unknown contact
                    // add number,name,message to list                     
                    sms.add("Number: " + address+ " .Name: Unknown .Message: " + body);
                }
                inboxCursor.moveToNext();
            }
        }
        return sms;
}
```

**EDIT :**

To group all sms from each contact:

```
    List<String> groupSms=new List<String>(); 
    // retrieve all contacts
    Cursor contacts=getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                    null,null,null,null);     
    if(contacts.getCount()>0)
    {
        contacts.moveToFirst();
        for(int i=0;i<contacts.getCount();i++)
        {    
             // get phone number       
             String phone_number=contacts.getString(contacts.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER)) ;
             // retrieve sms of phone_number from inbox
             Cursor sms=getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, "address='"+phone_number+"'", null,null);
             if(sms.getCount()>0)
             {
                  sms.moveToFirst();
                  for(int j=0;j<sms.getCount();j++)
                  {
                      // get sms body
                      String text=sms.getString(sms.getColumnIndex("body"));    
                      // add "phone_number" and "text" to a list
                      groupSms.add(phone_number+":"+text);
                      // move to next sms from phone_number
                      sms.moveToNext();
                  }
             }
             //move to next contact
             contacts.moveToNext();
        }
    }
```

Comment: yes thanks a lot thats what i was looking for....but now i need to group all the sms from the same contact...and there are some contacts that saved that also contains the country code...its a difference of country code only but it wont show..how can  i accomplish these two things?

Comment: @kashifmehmood: i have updated my answer.And you should also try to code it yourself.We cannot write complete code for you.From above code,you will get idea how it works.Try to write code and then bring problem to SO.

Comment: the code doesnot works....it does not groups the sms from the same number,,,, and sometimes gives nullpointerexception..but sometimes works fine but dont group the sms from the same number....

Comment: what you get at the end,in groupSms object? list them out.

Comment: u mean returning the groupSms object to the list....? well i did that also but nothing happens....

Comment: @kashifmehmood: try loging the values under the statement groupSms.add(phone_number+":"+text); in my above code of grouping sms for a contact.

Answer (score 1):

check out this code....

```
String phone_number = contacts
                        .getString(contacts
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                Log.i(null, "Stage 12");
                // retrieve sms of phone_number from inbox
                Cursor sms = getContentResolver().query(
                        Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null,
                        "address='" + phone_number + "'", null, null);
                Log.i(null, "Stage 13");


                if (sms.getCount() > 0) {
                    Log.i(null, "Stage 14");

                    sms.moveToFirst();
                    for (int j = 0; j < sms.getCount(); j++) {
                        Log.i(null, "Stage 15");

                        // get sms body
                        String text = sms.getString(sms.getColumnIndex("body"));
                        // add "phone_number" and "text" to a list
                        groupSms.add(phone_number + ":" + text);
                        Log.i(null, "Stage 16");

                        // move to next sms from phone_number
                        sms.moveToNext();
                    }
                }
                // move to next contact
                contacts.moveToNext();
            }
        }
        Log.i(null, "Stage 9");
        return groupSms;
```

the code mentioned below never executes....it is a part of the above code...

```
if (sms.getCount() > 0) {
                        Log.i(null, "Stage 14");

                        sms.moveToFirst();
                        for (int j = 0; j < sms.getCount(); j++) {
                            Log.i(null, "Stage 15");

                            // get sms body
                            String text = sms.getString(sms.getColumnIndex("body"));
                            // add "phone_number" and "text" to a list
                            groupSms.add(phone_number + ":" + text);
                            Log.i(null, "Stage 16");

                            // move to next sms from phone_number
                            sms.moveToNext();
                        }
```

its giving me quite a headache...i cant figure out why this code never executes... i am running the code on my Galaxy...

any help guys...?

Answer (score 0):

When you are dealing with phone numbers, it (https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/) may helps to generalize it.... :)